Type inference error when generic class constructor builds an instance of another generic class with bounded type
When type parameter is bounded (T extends Comparable<? super T>), I encounter a type inference problem using <> to let the compiler infer the type in the following example:
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class InferTypeArgApp {
    static class ACollection<E extends Comparable<? super E>> {
    // static class ACollection<E> {  // <-- If E isn't bounded, BCollection can use <>
        private Set<E> mySet;

        ACollection(Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
            mySet = new TreeSet<>(comparator);
        }
    }

    static class BCollection<E extends Comparable<? super E>> {
        private ACollection<E> myACollection;

        BCollection(Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
            myACollection = new ACollection<>(comparator);
            //              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <-- Cannot infer type
            //                                                arguments for
            //                                                ACollection<>Java(16778094)
            //
            // myACollection = new ACollection<E>(comparator);  // <-- This works
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ACollection<Integer> col = new ACollection<>(null); // <-- Java manages to
                                                            //     implicitly infer
                                                            //     the type here
    }
}

If I declare ACollection as class ACollection<E extends Comparable<? super E>> then I get the type argument inference error. However, if it's declared as class ACollection<E> then there is no error.
The way I see it, Java compiler has enough information to infer that ACollection I initialize in BCollection constructor has type argument E regardless of whether ACollection type argument extends anything.
Why is there a type inference error?
For completeness, here is the full compilation error which didn't clarify anything for me but hopefully someone can parse it:
$ /usr/local/java/jdk/bin/javac -Xdiags:verbose InferTypeArgApp.java
InferTypeArgApp.java:20: error: cannot infer type arguments for ACollection<>
            myACollection = new ACollection<>(comparator);
                            ^
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) E#1
    (argument mismatch; Comparator<CAP#1> cannot be converted to Comparator<? super E#3>)
  where E#1,E#2,E#3 are type-variables:
    E#1 extends Comparable<? super E#1> declared in class ACollection
    E#2 extends Comparable<? super E#2> declared in class BCollection
    E#3 extends CAP#1,Comparable<? super E#3>
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object super: E#2 from capture of ? super E#2
1 error


I doubt there is much useful insight to be gained here, especially for such an unusual design, as rzwitserloot pointed out. If I were to answer, I'd essentially just be going through the language specification, starting from 15.9.3, and eventually go to Chapter 18 where the type inference happens.

Your class definition makes no sense.
You pick a door: You do one of the below 2 strategies. You've tried to do both which is nonsensical:

The objects in your 'thing that cares about ordering' have a natural order. In other words, these objects know how to sort themselves against other instances of their own type. Integer is an example of a class whose instances can do that: I can ask an Integer itself where it falls on the ordering relative to some other instance of integer:

Integer i = 5;
Integer j = 10;
i.compareTo(j); // returns negative to indicate i is lower.

To represent this, you can set up your generics bounds to indicate the type, whatever it is, needs to be able to compare itself to other Es. You tried this - that's what <E extends Comparable<? super E>> for.
You do not need a comparator and they make no sense here. The whole point of Comparable is that you do not need one - these objects can compare themselves to themselves already.

Alternatively, you pass the constructor of your 'thing that cares about the ordering' an oracle that can determine which one of any 2 instances that the thing operates on - is before the other one (or if they are ordering-wise the same). You do that by asking for a Comparator<? super E>. __You do not need or want E to be extends Comparable in this case!

You've done both. The fact that this doesn't work, is irrelevant, because it's nonsensical to do both. The point of passing a Comparator is that your generics type does not need to be Comparable.
You should look at the source of TreeSet which is walking exactly the same fine line you are trying to walk: A TreeSet has 2 separate ways you can construct one:

Don't pass a comparator - just new TreeSet<>(). However, TreeSet demands that the generics type of your set is Comparable. Because if not, TreeSet cannot work. It needs somebody to tell it how to order things.

Do pass a comparator - new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDERING) for example. In this case, TreeSet doesn't care what the generics type is. It can be anything; it does not need to extend Comparable.


Unfortunately, TreeSet has 'solved' the problem by tossing in the towel.
This is perfectly legal, in that it compiles fine:
Set<InputStream> sortedStreams = new TreeSet<>();

It compiles. It shouldn't, because that code is compile-time-detectable nonsense. InputStreams do not know how to sort themselves. If you add anything to this treeset, it'll cause an exception immediately.
But.. you can do better!
Make the constructor private and instead use static methods that serve as constructors. Now you can give those static methods the proper generics!
Here's what TreeSet should have looked like:
// Current, 'broken' TreeSet:

public class TreeSet<E> {
  private final TreeMap<E, Object> backingMap;
  public TreeSet() {
    backingMap = new TreeMap<>();
  }
}

// This is what it should have been

public class TreeSet<E> {
  private final TreeMap<E, Object> backingMap;

  private TreeSet(Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
    this.backingMap = new TreeMap<>(comparator);
  }

  public static <E> TreeSet<E> usingComparator(Comparator<? super E> comparator$
    return new TreeSet<>(comparator);
  }

  public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> TreeSet<E> naturalOrder() {
    return new TreeSet<>(Comparator.naturalOrder());
  }
}

TreeSet doesn't have this, probably because the existing somewhat broken constructors are unlikely to go away (java prefers not to bother maintainers existing code that works perfectly fine with the burden of having to update it), and if they stay, also having a bunch of static methods is perhaps overkill.
Then again, that exact path (constructors that should have been static methods, then adding the methods while keeping the constructors, then marking the constructors @Deprecated) is what Integer and Long went through, so, maybe one day.
At any rate, you can now use the better solution, you're not burdened by having to hold backwards compatibility in high regard.

Hey thanks for the answer, but I don’t think it’s addressing my question.

The question was about why Java compiler could not infer the type even though it’s pretty clear that it’s .

Nevertheless your answer did make me go down the source code of TreeSet and see what a mess it can sometimes be even though it works.

That's the problem with simplified examples, @nhtrnm - In this specific case your example was so incredibly badly chosen it made it look like your underlying question was different.
